# Alert in RAM/CPU Usage Detection in e-Commerce Server

Tags: neural-network, anomaly-detection

Currently I'm building my monitoring services for my e-commerce Server, which mostly focus on CPU/RAM usage. It's likely Anomaly Detection on Timeseries data.

My approach is **building LSTM Neural Network to predict next CPU/RAM value on chart trending** and **compare with STD (standard deviation) value multiply with some number (currently is 10)**

But in real life conditions, it depends on many differents conditions, such as:

1- Maintainance Time (in this time "anomaly" is not "anomaly")

2- Sales time in day-off events, holidays, etc., RAM/CPU usages increase is normal, of courses

3- If percentages of CPU/RAM decrement are the same over 3 observations: 5 mins, 10 mins & 15 mins -> Anomaly. But if 5 mins decreased 50%, but 10 mins it didn't decrease too much (-5% ~ +5%) -> Not an "anomaly".

Currently I detect anomaly on formular likes this:

```
isAlert = (Diff5m >= 10 && Diff10m >= 15 && Diff30m >= 40)
```

**where Diff is Different Percentage in Absolute value.**

Unfortunately I don't save my "pure" data for building neural network, for example, when it detects anomaly, I modified that it is not an anomaly anymore.

I would like to add some attributes to my input for model, such as **isMaintenance, isPromotion, isHoliday, etc.** but sometimes it leads to overfitting.

I also want to my NN can adjust baseline over the time, for example, when my Service is more popular, etc.

There are any hints on these aims?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say that an anomaly is an unusual outcome, i.e. a outcome that's not expected given the inputs. As you've figured out, there are a few variables that *are* expected to influence CPU and RAM usage. So why not feed those to the network? That's the whole point of Machine Learning. Your network will make a prediction of CPU usage, taking into account the sales volume, whether there is (or was) a maintenance window, etc.

Note that you probably don't need an `isPromotion` input if you include actual sales volumes. The former is a discrete input, and only captures a fraction of the information present in the `totalSales` input

Machine Learning definitely needs data. If you threw that away, you'll have to restart capturing it. As for adjusting the baseline, you can achieve that by overweighting recent input data.